# How to know when the user downloads a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter app and wish to publish it after I am done. However, there is a tutorial I want to show when the user downloads the app and opens it for the very first time.

`User downloads the app` → `Opens it` → `Sees tutorial` → `Uses app` → `Closes it` → `Opens second time` → `Doesn't see tutorial`

I want to make sure that this tutorial is only shown the first time the user opens the app. How can I sense this in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like package:shared_preferences.  Look for a key with a specific value.  If it's absent, show the tutorial, then set the preference.

You can even make it a version number, so if you have "new news" to show, you can release an app that looks for an updated number, and upon not seeing it, repeats the whole intro, or just a portion of it as relevant.